# "docker context ls" or "docker context use default" causes "context requires credentials to be passed as environment variables"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command-line-interface, amazon-ecs

When I use the Docker command `docker context ls` or `docker context use default` the error
`context requires credentials to be passed as environment variables` is printed in the console output.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen when the current context in use has the "AWS environment variables" setting and the AWS variables are not set. Set the variables to random characters to switch context.

```bash
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=any-value
    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=any-value
    export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=any-value
```

Now you can switch context using the command `docker context use default`